# AJAX General Error Handling

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, spring-mvc

I am currently working on an existing system wherein I have to create a generic error handling for the entire system. The system is using Spring MVC and also AJAX.

Now I have done the error handling for normal requests (not using ajax)
but I am having problems with the AJAX part. In the AJAX part, if there is an error/exception, the page does not redirect to the generic error page that I created. It stays on the same screen and nothing happens.

I have done my research regarding this and it seems that for the AJAX part, I need to do it by jQuery redirect.

Since I am working with an existing system, I want to minimize the changes to be made. So my question is:
Is it possible to create a generic method that the AJAX part can call automatically without adding additional codes to the 'error:' part of the AJAX call?

Any suggestions would be gladly accepted. :D

Comment: You can register an `ajaxError` event handler.  Here is jQuery's [documentation](https://api.jquery.com/ajaxError/#callback) for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can register an `ajaxError` event.  Here is jQuery's [documentation](https://api.jquery.com/ajaxError/#callback) for it.

A code example:

```
$( document ).ajaxError(function() {
  //do your redirect(s) here
});
```

and a [JSFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/8e7td5qj/1/)

Note that I wanted to simply display the gist of using it, but you can also get which `jqXHR` object threw the error / re-route depending on which one it was.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look here for [generic error handling](http://ankursinghal86.blogspot.in/2014/07/exception-handling-in-spring-mvc.html)

Have a look at below working example from my application.

My **ExceptionController**

```
 @ExceptionHandler(Exception.class)
    public ModelAndView getExceptionPage(Exception e, HttpServletRequest request) {
        BaseLoggers.exceptionLogger.error("Exception in Controller", e);

        if (isAjax(request)) {

            ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView("forward:/app/webExceptionHandler/ajaxErrorRedirectPage");
            request.setAttribute("errorMessageObject", e.toString());
            return model;

        } else {

            ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView("forward:/app/webExceptionHandler/nonAjaxErrorRedirectPage");
            request.setAttribute("errorMessageObject", e.toString());
            request.setAttribute("errorViewName", "error");
            return model;

        }

    }
```

//**AnotherController** where request is forwarded.

```
    // this mapping is responsible for rendering view for all exceptions in nonAjax calls.
    @RequestMapping(value = "/nonAjaxErrorRedirectPage")
    public String nonAjaxErrorRedirectPage(HttpServletRequest request, Model model) {

        Locale loc = RequestContextUtils.getLocale(request);
        String nonAjaxErrorMsg = messageSource.getMessage("label.error.msg.nonAjaxCalls", null, loc);
        model.addAttribute("errorMessage", nonAjaxErrorMsg);
        String errorViewName = (String) request.getAttribute("errorViewName");
        return errorViewName;
    }

    // this mapping is responsible for sending error message with suitable error code for all exceptions in Ajax calls.
    @RequestMapping(value = "/ajaxErrorRedirectPage")
    @ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)
    @ResponseBody
    public String ajaxErrorRedirectPage(HttpServletRequest request, Model model) {
        Locale loc = RequestContextUtils.getLocale(request);
        String ajaxErrorMsg = messageSource.getMessage("label.error.msg.ajaxCalls", null, loc);
        return ajaxErrorMsg;
    }
```